# Prisma multiple row update in single query timeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, prisma

Wrapping a query into a transaction like:

```
await prisma.$transaction(async (tx) => {
    req.body.products.forEach(async (product) => {
      await tx.product.update({
        where: {
          id: product.id,
        },
        data: {
          someField: product.data,
        },
      });
    });
  });
```

Just straight up fails due to timeout (20s+).

Anyone have any workarounds???

Funny thing is it works for up to 20 items in the array (still slow) but anything more than 20 just timesout.

Even putting the queries into a await prisma.$transaction([]) fails. The updates are super tiny and if its done individually, it gets updated in a matter of ms. But 20 in a row just goes poof. The timeout of 20s is enforced by db (planetscale)